# What is the proper procedure to remove an IMAP folder from the server while using mbsync?

Tags: email, imap, offlineimap

I started playing around with `mbsync` to download my IMAP email to a local MailDir folder.
I have around 80 folders and subfolders in the IMAP server.

I noticed that when deleting one of the folders from the server when I run mbsync it recreates it.
The only way I've got it working is by deleting the folder in the remote and locally **before** syncing.

Is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

Based on its description, setting the `Remove Both` Channel option seems like do what you want.

though fwiw, `Remove Slave` did not help me. mbsync still complains

```
Warning: channel myaccount: master ParentFolder/ChildFolder cannot be opened and slave ParentFolder/ChildFolder not empty.
```